# GroovyShell: Redirect stderr to StringWriter

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

I'm trying to run a groovy script from java and capture both stdout and stderr.
I was able to capture the stdout using the following code:

```
StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setProperty("out", output);
new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate(scriptText);
```

I couldn't figure out how to capture stderr. I already tried:

```
binding.setProperty("err", output);
```

and

```
binding.setProperty("stderr", output);
```

none are working.

Comment: you could redirect stderr only for whole java runtime: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr-java.io.PrintStream-

Comment: I'm building a service that executes groovy scripts. So at a given time, there might be multiple executions and for each one of them I need to capture both out and err

Comment: no need. just use `try{ evaluate(...) }catch{Throwable t ...}` to catch error. you don't need sdterror.

Comment: I’m already catching any exception. stderr is useful when the groovy script has System.err.println